# allocate more memory to void * on iteration and then add the value

Tags: c++, memory-management, mysql++

I have a memory allocation problem with an implementation of a column-store database system. This, in particular is part of implementing a MySql connector to import a table into my database.

Say I have the following vector:

```
 std::vector <void *> data;
```

I have a function that checks for types to add data to the pointer as follows:
As you can see, for each column we have a void * added to the vector.

```
for(int c = 0; c != numCols; c++){

      // ...
      case BOOL_TYPE: {
                 bool *b;
                 data.push_back((void *) b);
             }
             break;
      // ... 
}
```

now another function that read the table rows needs to add the data

```
    while (mysqlpp::Row row = res.fetch_row()) {
                    for (int c = 0; c != numCols; c++) {
                        // ...
                        switch (colType){
                    case BOOL_TYPE: {
                        if(!isNull){
                            bool val = row[c];
                            data[c] = new char[sizeof(val)];
                            data[c] = val;
                        }
                    }
                    break;

                   //... more types

                }



                    }
   }
```

I am concerned about these lines:

```
 data[c] = new char[sizeof(val)];
 data[c] = val;
```

I am very new to C++ and memory management so I am not sure how I can allocate more memory to the void * each time and then add the value?

**EDIT**
This is for a column-store database where I am storing the data in columns not rows. 
To be clear, I need a clean way of adding the data from mySQL which is a row-store database into my columns.

An easy solution to my problem would be if I can get the number of rows in a table using MySql++? Then I can allocate that many rows * (size of datattype) bytes initially and fill this memory in.

Comment: Both code snippets look suspect. In the first the code pushes an uninitialized pointer, so it can't be dereferenced. The second code snippet have a memory leak (you allocate memory and store a pointer to it in `data[c]`, then *overwrite* the pointer to point to something else).

Comment: what is the correct way of doing this then? this is why I posted the code structure, Thanks

Comment: I suggest you start looking at e.g. [Boost Any](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/any.html). And try to not store pointers.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg thanks I appreciate the link. I want a quick solution without boost if possible

Answer (score 1):

Using raw dynamic allocated arrays gets inconvenient quite quickly and it is memory leak prone.

I suggest using a variant type to store the values without having to do manual memory management. E.g. [`boost::variant`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/variant.html):

```
typedef boost::variant<
    std::nullptr_t, // for DB NULL
    bool,           // for DB BOOL
    intmax_t,       // for DB Integers
    double,         // for DB Reals
    std::string     // for DB varchar
    > Value;
```

And then:

```
//...
data.push_back(Value()); // nullptr value
```

Or just `data.resize(column_count)`.

and later:

```
// ...
bool val = row[c];
data[c] = val;
```

---

There are two major ways to treat database data:

1. **Strongly-typed.** In which case your in-memory columns store the exact type, e.g. `std::vector<int>` for an Integer DB column. Or, row-wise, a record `struct` is defined for each query, rows stored as `std::vector<Record>`.
2. **Weakly-typed.** Something like `std::vector<Variant>` for columns, or `std::vector<std::vector<Variant>>` for rows. It is hard to make a better variant type than `boost::variant` though.

Looks like you use the *weakly-typed* way with `void*` being the variant type. `void*` is type unsafe, meaning no errors are caught at compile time, e.g. memory management errors, like casting `void*` to a wrong type; or forgetting to free the memory or freeing it more than once. Using `void*` considerably increases the risk of a crash or corruption for no apparent reason. You may like to rethink your design sooner rather than later.

Comment: large part of the database I am working with is based on data being a vector of void * (void pointers), I would prefer your solution but how would it be done better?

Comment: @Saher Added a note for you.

Comment: I appreciate your response and agree that this is elegant but the project I am part of has performance as the highest priority so boost is probably not an option

Answer (score 0):

For a quick (and in my opinion) dirty solution that might work with the code you have, is to *copy* the data, not overwrite the pointer and thereby getting a memory leak (as well as the possibility of having the data it points to disappear any moment).

First of all, instead of just initializing it you allocate memory that you can later free:

```
case BOOL_TYPE: {
    data.push_back(new bool);
    break;
```

Then when setting proper data, you first free the existing memory, then reallocate it while setting the value:

```
case BOOL_TYPE: {
    if(!isNull){
        delete data[c];
        data[c] = new bool(row[c]);
    }
}
break;
```

Comment: and does that line `data[c] = new bool(row[c])` allocate the memory in sequence? so I can for instance retrieve `data[c][i]`?

Comment: @Saher No, but then neither does the current code you have (as shown in the question). My impression is that `data` is already indexed by column, do you mean to index it *by row* instead?

Comment: I mean what if I want to know the value of the 4th entry in the first column (data[0])? will `data[0][3]` work? or something like `data[0] + 3*sizeof(bool)`

Comment: @Saher First you have to defined which "dimension" you want to be the rows, and which ones you want to be the columns. Should it be `data[row][column]` or (like you seem to want) `data[column][row]`?

Comment: @Saher Actually it's *not* that way, For the example shown you allocate only a single byte to fit a single `bool`, and you do it over and over again in a loop leaking memory in every loop.

Comment: @Saher I'm trying to think of a way to help you solve it but can't think of anything right now. I think you need to look over your design a bit more. Worst case, you have to redo the design. (Especially since the common is to to have row-major indexing.) The major problem is that you need to allocate the rows *before* you actually know what type they are, and so can't really allocate them properly (it seems to me).

Comment: So how to do it the right way. My question is "allocate more memory to void *" I realize I am only allocating one byte and overwriting it.

Comment: It is a column-store database so the other way is not an option. Thanks for your comments and help though. I appreciate it.

Comment: @Saher I'm sorry I couldn't be of more help. You might want to update the question with some of the information you told in these comments (like it's a column-sttore db, that you want to use e.g. `data[column][row]` etc.) Will help the next one trying to answer.